# Ruby program doesn't save hash changes

Tags: ruby, hash, save

My source code:

```
books = {
    Harry_Potter: 5,
    Steve_Jobs: 10
}

def finder(bookName)
    books.each {
            |n| if n == bookName
                puts "Are you sure you want to #{choice} #{n}?"
                confirmAction = gets.chomp
                    if confirmAction == "yes" 
                    case choice
                        when "update"
                            puts "Enter the new name:"
                            newName = gets.chomp.to_sym
                            books[newName.to_sym] = books.delete(n)
                            puts "Update the rating for #{newName}:"
                            newRating = gets.chomp.to_i
                            books[newName.to_sym] = newRating.to_i
                            puts "Successfully updated #{newName} with rating of #{newRating}"

                        when "delete"
                            books.delete(n)

                        else puts "Invalid option!"
                    end

                else puts "Invalid book name."
                end
            end

            }
end


puts "What would you like to do?\n[Add] [Update] [Delete] [View]"
action = gets.chomp.capitalize

case action
    when "Add"
        puts "Enter the new book name:"
        title = gets.chomp.to_sym
        puts "Please rate the book [1-10]:"
        rating = gets.chomp.to_i
        books[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
        puts "Successfully added #{title} with rating of #{rating}"
        puts books

    when "Update"
        choice = "update"
        puts "Enter the name of the book:"
        bookName = gets.chomp.to_sym
        finder(bookName)

    when "Delete"
        choice = "delete"
        puts "Enter the name of the book:"
        bookName = gets.chomp.to_sym
        finder(bookName)

    when "View"
        choice = "view"
        puts books.each {
            |k, v| puts "#{k}: #{v}"
        }
    end
```

Whenever I use **add** option and add something it works. But once I exit and re-open the program, it doesn't show books that I've added using the **add** option, it returns to the default list.
I need Ruby to save all the changes permanently.

Comment: Side note, it's a convention in Ruby to use 2-space instead of 4-space indent.

Comment: Permenantly? Then you should have a storage like a database or a file output.

Comment: I don't see anything being written to a file.  That's the only way you can save changes.

Comment: @Santosh I thought Ruby will write list in the file, but anyway thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save your objects yourself, e.g. using [`YAML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html):

```
require 'yaml'
File.write('data.yml', YAML.dump(books))
```

The contents of "data.yml" will be:

```
---
:Harry_Potter: 5
:Steve_Jobs: 10
```

To read the file use:

```
books = YAML.load(File.read('data.yml'))
#=> {:Harry_Potter=>5, :Steve_Jobs=>10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use [Maglev](http://maglev.github.io) which is a ruby interpreter based on the [GemStone/S Object Server](http://gemtalksystems.com/index.php/products/gemstones/) which will be able to store your books persistently (by setting a reference to your `books` Hash and `Maglev.commit_transaction`). However this might be a bit of an overkill for your purposes :-)